# Is it correct to invoke the constructor of a JavaScript Object in one of the prototype functions?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am reviewing a JavaScript code from a colleague and he wrote an Object prototype function that I believe is not correct regarding the principles of Object-Oriented Programming.

```
Game.prototype.reset = function() {
    if (game.over) {
        game.over = false;
        game = new Game(players);
    }    
}
```

A couple of lines below, the game variable was declared as a global variable.

```
var game = new Game(players);
```

So, is it correct to create a new Game object from one of its constructors? The code perfectly runs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He should not reference the variable `game` inside the prototype method, as `game` is the name of the instance. Instead he should use `this` to refer to the current object.

Inside the `reset` method he should not created the new game instance but truly reset the Game fields, something along below:

```
Game.prototype.reset = function() {
    if (this.over) {
        this.over = false;
        this.initialize(this.players);
    }    
}

Game.prototype.initialize = function(players) {
    this.players = players;
    :
}
```

Comment: You assume that `reset` is supposed to reset the instance it is called on. That may not be the case.

Comment: @Oriol Then why put it on the prototype?  This probably isn't a great question for SO, but this would certainly raise some questions in a code review.

Comment: @JamesMontagne For example, because the constructor could be defined inside a scope you don't have access to. Only some instances might have been exported outside, so the method has been put in the prototype instead of e.g. the constructor. Probably not the case, but still possible.

Comment: @Oriol "You assume that reset is supposed to reset the instance it is called on." That's what the principle of encapsulation is.

Comment: @Oriol In object-oriented programming class is responsible for its content. Thus by declaring a class `reset` method the author implies the functionality is for that Class only. If it was for the collection of games than I would assume other class i.e `GameCollection` will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I guest this broke the encapsulation principle, each instance is responsable to deal with his own behavior, not with other global instance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

If was me, i would choose Max Zoom alternative to model my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is "incorrect" code inasmuch as it disobeys the principle of encapsulation, because one instance of a class is affecting the state another instance of that class, without that second instance being passed as a parameter (it just comes out of nowhere).

I'd also say that it's not particularly useful to define a module part way between a constructor and a singleton.

If `game` is to be a singleton, then define it as a singleton, attach it to the global scope (or better, use a module loader), and use it as a singleton.  Give it a `reset` method that uses `this` to change its own internal state back to initial values.

If `Game` is to be a constructor, of which there can be many instances, then define it as a constructor and create instances when necessary, then pass those instances around as parameters where needed.

Personally I would use a constructor, and I wouldn't have a `reset` method at all.  When the game is reset by the user, I'd just create a new instance of `Game`.  But a properly defined singleton would be better than the code that's in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong in using `Game` constructor inside prototype of `Game`.

See the below example. it has a method named `cloneMe` and it creates new object with current objects value.

```js
function Game(name, team) {
  this.playerName = name;
  this.teamName = team
  this.points = 0;
}

Game.prototype.goal = function() {
  this.points += 1;
}

Game.prototype.cloneMe = function() {
  return new Game(this.playerName, this.teamName);
}


var gameInst = new Game('jack', 'X-team');

gameInst.goal();
gameInst.points // will print 1

gameInst.goal();
gameInst.points // will print 2

// game varible got replaced with new variable
var gameCloneInst = game.cloneMe();

gameCloneInst.goal();
gameCloneInst.points // will print 1
```

Comment: This is fine, but it's different from the code in the question.  Your `cloneMe` method returns a new instance of `Game`.  The code in the question has a method that modifies a variable defined outside of the `Game` constructor.